# Cross-reference code and business requirements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

I was curious if a tool exists to collect Metadata references in code to somehow link business requirements with sections of code?

I'm currently working on a legacy system that does not do anything like this, so I'm envisioning a Visual Studio extension that allows me to define Metadata tags. Once they are defined, I can add them to sections of code such that they are searchable.

So, for example, if I am working on the billing subsystem, perhaps I add the [Billing] tag so the next developer knows the specific part of the code that I used as an entry point into the code.

Is this a thing? Or could this even be leveraged to be useful? I just find that I am often lost for months learning a new system and always wished there was a way to search the code for business requirements. Or at least had a dictionary of search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a problem is that business requirements may not map directly to any kind of module, but may be spread over the code-base. So where would you put your tags?

Requirements may also change, so you might have tags linking to requirements that may no longer accurately describe the current behavior.

I would propose to instead document such requirements thru tests. Preferably automated tests whenever possible, but in some cases manual tests might be appropriate. This should let you know whenever a requirement are no longer fulfilled, and that lets you either change the test, or the product. Such test can also be useful if you are new to the code base to gain some understanding of how the code is intended to work.

Having a good architecture, appropriate code comments, and some kind of project architecture documentation are other common tools to make familiarization easier, but it is fairly rare that all of these things exist and are up to date.

Linking source code to external systems can be somewhat risky, since code tend to outlive systems and people. I have worked with code bases that have gone thru at least 4 different source control systems, and three different issue trackers. And even if you think having such tags is the best thing since sliced bread, you successor might consider it unnecessary bloat.

Comment: So, no such tool exists? To answer your questions: I was envisioning a Metadata tag dictionary. The business requirements would be generalized. Multiple tags could be put on a single block of code. The primary target for the tag is the entry point. Ex: in an ordering system, maybe I add a Metadata tag for [Browse catalog]. This is not pointing to any external source. There could be multiple entry points into the Browse Catalog functionality, but rather than going through hundreds of files, these tags maybe point me to four entry points.

Comment: Functionality for browsing the catalog is not likely to get a massive change in business requirements.

Comment: But, now I don't need to know that the ProductList function is not actually used for browsing the catalog. Maybe that is used to create an accounting report. Rather than waste half the day reading code for a completely different part of the system, I can focus in on the parts of the system I actually want to look at.

Comment: @SlipEternal I'm not aware of any such tool. If you want to check if some function is used for some feature, the quickest option is often to place a breakpoint in the function and use the feature. That lets you with certainty know if the function is used.

Comment: that requires I be an expert in the system and know all entry points to a specific feature. As you rightly pointed out, that means I need to know about the current development as well as legacy development entry points ahead of time. I need to know about the new React page, the old aspx page, and the older asp page that each touch the feature. A few clients required functionality that was discontinued (but not removed from support) and occasionally continue to use the legacy application for that functionality. I don't know where to place the breakpoint.